# Chrome: any way to sync extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering if there is any way to have the same chrome extensions installed in 2 computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Chrome Sync](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185277) synchronizes installed apps & extensions between your
  computers;
- [chrome.storage API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html) allows developers to synchronize the
  apps'/extensions' data between user computers via Chrome Sync.